# Databricks UNKNOWN_FIELD_EXCEPTION.NEW_FIELDS_IN_FILE

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

When running a notebook in Databricks, it is returning the following error: `[UNKNOWN_FIELD_EXCEPTION.NEW_FIELDS_IN_FILE] Encountered unknown fields during parsing: [<field_name>], which can be fixed by an automatic retry: true`

The documentation here https://docs.databricks.com/error-messages/unknown-field-exception-error-class.html is not clearly on why that error exists.

The dataframe is configured to use a schema as follows.

```py
def bronze_ingestion(table_group, table_name, table_state):
    df = (spark.readStream
        .format("cloudFiles")
        .option("cloudFiles.format", "csv")
        .option("cloudFiles.allowOverwrites", True)
        .option("multiLine", True)
        .option("quote", '"')
        .option("escape", '"')
        .option("pathGlobFilter", "*.csv")
        .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", f"{source_storage}/{source_base_folder}-schema/{project_code}/{table_group}/{table_name}/{table_state}")
        .load(f"{source_storage}/{source_base_folder}/{project_code}/{table_group}/{table_name}/{table_state}")
        .select("*", 
            col("_metadata.file_path").alias("source_file"),
            current_timestamp().alias("processing_time")
        )
    )

    df = set_safe_column_names(df)

    df = df.withColumn("lake_id", row_uuid())
    df = df.withColumn("date_import", date_import_from_source_file(df['source_file']))

    streamWriter = (df.writeStream
        .option("overwriteSchema", "true")
        .option("mergeSchema", "true")
        .option("checkPointLocation", f"{source_storage}/{source_base_folder}-checkpoint/{project_code}/{table_group}/{table_name}/{table_state}")
        .trigger(availableNow=True)
        .toTable(f"`{bronze_catalog}`.`{bronze_schema}`.`{table_group}_{table_name}_{table_state}`")
    )

    streamWriter.awaitTermination()

    return streamWriter
```

What can be causing that parsing error?

Comment: Can you post code which creates this data frame?

Comment: Could you please provide sample data frame along with tried code?

Comment: @Bhavani I've edited as requested.

Comment: Could you please provide sample data and related schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[UNKNOWN_FIELD_EXCEPTION.NEW_FIELDS_IN_FILE] Encountered unknown fields during parsing: [<field_name>]**, The above error indicates that the structure of the data being read from the CSV files doesn't match the expected schema.

According to the documentation you gave
**Unknown fields inside file path:**

For example I have a csv file that I have updated with 2 new columns and uploaded to the ADLS's samplefiles directory.

When you are reading the file from the source and Autoloader finds the new columns not matching the schema.
Autoloader adds a new column called Rescued record schema: `<newColumnsInRecordSchema>`
**Source file:**

[image]

In the below code I am reading the source file from ADLS with 2 extra columns then writing the data from source file adding 1 new column.
in **DELTA** format to ADLS into Autoloader folder.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from delta.tables import DeltaTable
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("DeltaWithAutomaticRetries").config("spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled", "true").getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.adlsgen2may15.dfs.core.windows.net", "ttCHZNZsg0M3x/WzGArHAh8ZPWKtVL8mMkct5DFAODJ46/yBA/T8U39xQ0obL12bGAT7XF1Hy4jw+AStkqafOQ==")
source_location = f'abfss://folder02@adlsgen2may15.dfs.core.windows.net/samplefiles/'
target_location = f'abfss://folder02@adlsgen2may15.dfs.core.windows.net/Autoloader/'
checkpoints_loc = f'abfss://folder02@adlsgen2may15.dfs.core.windows.net/Checkpoints/'
schema_loc = f'abfss://folder02@adlsgen2may15.dfs.core.windows.net/schema/'
df = (
spark.readStream.format('cloudFiles')
.option('cloudFiles.format', 'CSV')
.option('cloudFiles.schemaLocation', schema_loc)
.load(source_location)
)
df_with_new_field = df.withColumn("new_column", lit("new_value"))
query = (
df_with_new_field.writeStream
.format("delta")
.option("checkpointLocation", checkpoints_loc)
.outputMode("append")
.start(target_location)
)
```

The below code will enable automatic retries for schema evolution in Delta Lake

```
SparkSession.builder.appName("DeltaWithAutomaticRetries").config("spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled", "true").getOrCreate()
```

The below image shows the 2 columns from the source and 1 new column added in the code.

[image]